# Laravel redirect to user dashboard when visiting login page if logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a basic login system setup, but I would like the user to be sent to there dashboard page if they try to access the "login" page or "create account" page.

How do I go about doing this?

I am thinking something in the routes file?:

```
Route::post('/login', array('uses' => 'UserController@login'));
Route::post('/create-account', array('uses' => 'UserController@createAccount'));

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', array('uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));

    Route::get('/logout', function () {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('/start');
    });
});
```

Perhaps some kind of group around the first two routes?

Answer (score 3):

A before filter is perfect for this. Since it basically will do the opposite of `auth` let's call it `no_auth`:

```
Route::filter('no_auth', function(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
}
```

And then wrap a group around your two routes to apply the filter:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'no_auth'), function(){
   Route::post('/login', array('uses' => 'UserController@login'));
   Route::post('/create-account', array('uses' => 'UserController@createAccount'));
});
```

### Edit

Actually, as [@afarazit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28254099/662581) points out, there's already a filter like that in `app/filters.php` called `guest`. You just have to change the redirect URL to `dashboard` and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a [filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) for what you want, check your `filters.php` for "guest"

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can use an Event listener like so:

```
Event::listen('user.login', function (){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
});


Event::listen('user.create', function (){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
});
```

You need a named controller for above like so:

```
Route::post('/login', array(
    'uses' => 'UserController@login',
    'as' => 'user.login'
));

Route::post('/create-account', array(
    'uses' => 'UserController@createAccount',
    'as' => 'user.create'
));
```

Comment: Am sorry posting this from adriod phone so formatting is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You may use a constructor and include a filter in it. Here is an example; You can modify your code according to the example.

```
public function __construct(SignInForm $signInForm)
{
    $this->signInForm = $signInForm;
    $this->beforeFilter('guest', ['except' => 'destroy']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If laravel version is 4.2

open your **app/filters.php** and add

```
Route::filter('no_auth', function(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
});
```

add your login and create account pages to your **app/routes.php** like below:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'no_auth'), function(){
    Route::post('/login', array('uses' => 'UserController@login'));
    Route::post('/create-account', array('uses' => 'UserController@createAccount'));

});
```

It worked for me.